# AWS auto scaling with docker compose

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker-compose, autoscaling

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong for auto scaling an EC2 with docker compose. The target groups can't make healthy checks and are termintaing instances. I'm new to AWS

What I did was:

1. creating an EC2 instance and installing everything I need.
2. exporting the EC2 as image
3. try the image by launching an instance from template (using user data (code below), right IAM, right security group) --> it works

```bash
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ubuntu/22-23-ict-architecture-27/deployment
git pull
touch .env
echo BUCKET=mediacontent-.... >> .env
echo REGION=us-east-1 >> .env
sudo /usr/local/bin/docker-compose up -d
```

4. create lauch template, same settings (change security group).
   [image: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndK0n.png)]
5. create load balancer with target group.
   [image: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcMyj.png)]

what I'm experiencing:
The target group is not able to get a ping from port 3000. It terminates the instances. Tried installing an nginx with port 80, and then it works...

It's driving me crazy.